# Prove that every ring without non-zero divisors can be embedded in ring with identity which has no non-zero divisors.

Tags: ring-theory

Prove that every ring without non-zero divisors can be embedded in a ring with identity which has no non-zero divisors.

I am not sure what we have to do here. In particular, I do not know the formal definition of an embedding. Wikipedia mentions the following definition for fields

> In field theory, an embedding of a field $E$ in a field $F$ is a ring homomorphism $\sigma:E \to F.$

But here I have a ring. Can use this definition?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but my understanding is that a "non-zero divisor" is an element that is not a zero divisor. Thus, in a ring without non-zero divisors all elements would be zero divisors (or have I gotten something wrong?). But this is impossible in a ring with unity, because $1$ cannot be a zero divisor since for any nonzero $x$ we have $1x = x \neq 0$.

Comment: What is the author's definition of zero divisor and of non-zero divisor?

Comment: @SuperMario: Perhaps you meant "no nonzero zero-divisors", rather than "no non-zero divisors"?

Comment: @quasi I think the question is from [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=TgjsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq) at the bottom of pg 16 and it is written exactly as the OP typed it. It seems strange to me, and in the preview I can't see the page where the author defines the term.

Comment: Yes the question is from this book.

Comment: Well as for the second part of your question, yes you should be able to use that definition, except you will want to add the requirement that it is injective I think. In general I've seen embedding to mean an injective morphism from one object to another. Note that a ring homomorphism from a field to a ring is necessarily injective, which is why it doesn't need to be specified in the definition you found. Between two rings you'd want to specify this.